# How can I use the same codebase written using SKIA and C++ on web? (SKIA + WebAssembly, c++)

Tags: c++, webassembly, skia

I am completely new in using SKIA as well as WebAssembly. I have build SKIA library on windows and currently using it with C++.
I heard of WASM which can convert C, C++ codebase to run on browser. I have tried that too with some sample native code written in C and achieved it. This is really awesome.

Now I am trying to build a framework which can run natively as well as on web with the same codebase. Is it possible to do with SKIA ? If yes, How can I do it ? There is very less information regarding this on the internet which is not that clear. So I thought of getting some information from here. Any help or pointers on this would be appreciated.

The goal is to write whole code using C++ and SKIA, build it on Windows. And I want to use WASM to convert the same code to run on the browser. How ?

Comment: https://skia.org/docs/user/modules/canvaskit/

Answer (score 1):

SKIA is using D3D or OpenGL to render, it also create a Window using system calls. WASM does not have any "system" calls, like any OS has. You have to virtualize all such calls as WASM module imports API.